# What is difference between findOne and find_one in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm new in mongodb. Anyone tell me the difference between **`findOne`** and **`find_one`** query in `mongodb`.

Comment: find_one is used in pymongo while findOne is for mongo shell and maybe for mongo with other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`findOne`** returns **one** document that satisfies the specified query criteria. If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the **first** document. If no document satisfies the query, it will returns **null**. It is a db collection's method in `MongoDB`.

**`find_one`** is a Python API wrapper around `find`. It will also returns a **single** document matching a query (or **None** if there are no matches).

`find_one` is used in `pymongo` and `findOne` is used in `mongo` shell

Comment: visit [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) for more.

Answer (score 5):

`findOne` is a db collection's method in MongoDB. `find_one` is a Python API wrapper around `find`. With PyMongo API's `find_one` you can send more parameters to control the output.

[`findOne` has filter and projection parameters](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) whereas [`find_one` has more parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195874/what-is-difference-between-findone-and-find-one-in-mongo): filter, projection, skip, limit etc.

If you using PyMongo, focusing on `find()` and `find_one()` will be more helpful than focusing on pure Mongo's `findOne`.